# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. This question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/540).

Comment: Nice _Blazing Saddles_ reference!

Comment: This looks good, except I'm not seeing the tagline when I hover over the image with IE 8.

Comment: I strongly support open source, gdal etc. are part of my mandatory personal toolkit and I've been actively involved in osgeo4w for several years. Yet I don't feel comfortable with the over representation of open source projects in the current ad submissions (at the moment, only FLOSS is present in the tool category). At the same time, I wouldn't just add something for ArcGIS on spec (for one particular example), because, well, they can do their own darn marketing. They get enough money and publicity from me anyway. I don't have a solution to this conundrum. I just needed to voice it.

Comment: Is anybody seeing these ads? I haven't noticed a single one. Are they perhaps being served by a non-SE site that's getting blocked?

Comment: I found the problem: an ad blocker add-in to a Web browser.  I had to turn it off completely to see the ads; giving permissions to stackexchange.com wasn't enough.

Answer (score 47):

[image: Open-Source Desktop GIS]

Comment: I'm glad somebody finally put this up! Although should it have the name included?

Comment: @AndyW yes ... I wondered the same. It probably should, but should it also explain its function? Something like `QGIS: Opensource Desktop GIS`? Or just `QGIS` ?

Comment: your the boss! I think either of those would be helpful, although what you have done so far is quite nice IMO, and there is no real pressing need to change it unless you (or someone else) feels like taking the initiative.

Comment: I agree that it needs a little more clarification -- the logo is not sufficient for those of us who have never seen it before, and therefore less likely to lead to a click.

Answer (score 47):

[image: GDAL - Geospatial Data Abstraction Library]

Answer (score 45):

[image: The Open Source Geospatial Foundation]

Comment: I've noticed on the main site because this image does not conform to the pixel standards, it is stretched in an odd way. It may be best to fix it (or shrink the image and pad it with whitespace?)

Comment: I switched the image size. Hopefully it works better

Answer (score 42):

[image: Free and OpenSource Geospatial Database]

Comment: Image size is 240x240, yet it still shows up.

Comment: I got it from the postgis SVN, should I resize it?

Comment: Since it works, I see no reason to.  I guess 220x250 is a _guideline_.

Comment: It appears SE scales the picture to fit, slimming down the elephant.

Comment: A bit of a diet at the beginning of the year doesn't hurt, right? Although the idea of a skinny elephant seems a bit sad...

Answer (score 37):

[image: @StackGIS]

Answer (score 26):

[image: Powerful Open-Source Desktop GIS]

Answer (score 18):

[image: MapServer Open Source web mapping]

Answer (score 16):

[image: GeoMeetup in San Francisco]

Answer (score 11):

[image: PyCon US 2013]

Answer (score 6):

[image: MapWindows GIS]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Society of Cartographers - UK]![Society of Cartographers - UK]

Comment: No click-through link? What is the society of cartographers?

Comment: fixed url and link tag

Answer (score 3):

[image: GIS for Transportation Symposium April 16-18]

Answer (score 3):

[image: The International Cartographic Association]

Answer (score 3):

[image: FOSS4G North America 2013]