# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- mapping and cartography resources
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### [Basic stats](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1968)

Comment: Is there a date they need to be submitted by to make it onto the 2013 roster?

Comment: @BradHards There is no deadline. Any ad in this thread, as long as it is above the 6 vote threshold, will be shown on the site. It doesn't matter how late into the year it achieves this score.

Comment: are community ads still alive? I only see stackexchange ads, wether I'm logged in or not ...

Comment: @Karussell It should be. Let me double check.

Comment: Sorry being stupid, but, are these paid-for or free ads?

Comment: @martin You shouldn't call yourself stupid for asking an honest question. These are free ads, basically they are a means for the community to spread awareness about things they think are interesting to the audience of the site.

Comment: @GraceNote Sometimes a little self-deprecation goes a long way ;-) Back to the ads: they all seem to be for free/OS software, which is reasonable. Is that the restriction? What about commercial software vendors who don't mind paying, as a way of supporting the fine work of GIS SE? Hmm, there must be a FAQ on this...

Answer (score 42):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 39):

[image: GDAL - Geospatial Data Abstraction Library]

Answer (score 33):

[image: Free and OpenSource Geospatial Database]

Answer (score 25):

[image: @StackGIS]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 21):

[image: MapServer Open Source web mapping]

Answer (score 19):

[image: OpenStreetMap]

Comment: I would suggest you get the original SVG from [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Logos) and crop/resize it to the correct size. It looks blurry and stretched vertically.

Comment: Thank You, It has been done

Comment: Looks much better. I would also suggest adding a caption: "OpenStreetMap" and "The Free Wiki World Map". Like this: http://1x57.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/free-wiki-world-map-openstreetmap-logo-uk-nonprofit.jpg

Answer (score 15):

[image: Geographic Resources Analysis Support System (GRASS GIS)]

Comment: Shouldn't the word GRASS appear with the icon?

Answer (score 10):

[image: Help extend the GIS/Mapping response to the Super Typhoon Haiyan Disaster. Sign This Petition]

Comment: Consider using a drop shadow or outline. Solid color text on a photographic background never looks good by itself.

Comment: Done, looks a lot better. Sorry it took so long, had no internet last night.

Answer (score 8):

[image: The Open Source Geospatial Foundation]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Fast Java Routing Engine]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Geodjango-A world-class geographic web framework]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: As a minimum, there should be _some_ kind of description/explanation at this end. Even after visiting the site, i couldn't see the point.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78127/how-to-start-a-local-gis-users-group

Answer (score 6):

[image: gvSIG]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Cartaro - Geospatial CMS]

Answer (score 5):

[image: OTB - Orfeo Toolbox is not a black box]