# "meet-up" tag for GIS.meta

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

i think there should be **meet-up** tag for all conference, meeting, congress, forum etc. to inform people. so we can tag Esri User Conference, FOSS4G, GIS Ostrava 2014, CalGIS, Health GIS...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all such questions should be considered off-topic (both on our main site and here on meta) and closed whenever they appear.  We have two other mechanisms for such purposes: [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) and [community promotion ads](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/community-promotion-ads-2013).  Although neither is used as much as they could (should?) be, that does not appear to be due to any deficiencies in their implementation.

Comment: WRT to community ads, I suggest also posting to chat when adding something new or otherwise drawing attention. I know I have a tendency to skip over the ad Q as "I've already read that" and miss new additions. Ex: I missed the FOSS4G additions until today, though they were added in April.

Comment: I think I'm coming to your way of thinking on conference questions being off-topic in both main and meta - perhaps discussing them on chat or advertising them as community promotion ads would work sometimes - or maybe on [**blog**](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/) at others - but there are plenty of social networking sites that may be more suited to this than GIS-SE which does not claim to cater for social networking.

Comment: It's because of a community promotion ad that I discovered and am registering for FOSS4G. Keep them coming!