# What GIS Stack Exchange avenues are available to enlist community support for Emergency?

Tags: discussion, advertising

As an example of an emergency encountered by a GIS professional:

> I am part of a small group that is trying to get signatures on an
>   online petition to get licensed aerial images put into the public
>   domain so that they can be used for disaster relief and humanitarian
>   mapping purposes. The Philippines is devastated after Hainan/Yolanda
>   and the responders are desperate to know where to go and badly need
>   maps and imagery to save lives. People are ready to map it if they can
>   get the imagery.

Are there any avenues available at GIS Stack Exchange where this information can be disseminated to its user base of GIS Professionals to enlist community support, while remaining within Stack Exchange guidelines?

Answer (score 3):

In light of the recent Nepal Earthquake and the question on Main titled [Remote sensing for Nepal Earthquake](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144041/remote-sensing-for-nepal-earthquake), I would like to suggest the following as a procedure that those seeking to enlist our community's support could follow.  It is based on comments by @whuber to this question.

1. Place a community advertisement by following the instructions at [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5156/115) to create an advert as an answer.

   - Be sure to use the question devoted to the current year because the Q&A that triggers community ads gets made anew each year.
   - Have that answer link to a page of requirements/resources related to the emergency.
2. Use Social Media (e.g. Twitter) to advertise that answer so that it can be quickly upvoted to the necessary 6 and beyond.

To see an example of the Community Ad posted by @MarkC after The Philippines was devastated by typhoons Hainan/Yolanda in 2013 see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3441.

Feel free to use the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) for any open-ended discussions like what to do in an emergency that requires GIS skills to assist its resolution.  That part of the GIS Stack Exchange is ideal for asking anything that is insufficiently focused or off-topic for the Main and Meta sites.